# How to charge a Card that is both Credit and Debt with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to charge the user in a food ordering app, I can save theyr card and charge them just fine.

But I'm facing a problem, I'm from Brazil and here we have cards that can be both Credit and Debit. I can't figure out how to tell the payment method which funding to use.

Here's how I'm creating the payment method:

```
var options = new PaymentMethodCreateOptions
            {
                Card = new PaymentMethodCardOptions
                {
                    Number = number,
                    Cvc = cvc,
                    ExpMonth = long.Parse(expMonth),
                    ExpYear = long.Parse(expYear)
                },
                Type = "card",            
            };
```

I'm using 'card' as the type right now, but it seems to default to charging the card as Credit Card.

Looking through the api documentation I can specify the type as:

> alipay, au_becs_debit, bacs_debit, bancontact, card, eps, fpx, giropay,
> grabpay, ideal, oxxo, p24, sepa_debit, sofort

I can't find a way to tell Stripe to charge the card as a Debit Card.

Is it possible for me to tell stripe which type of funding should be used to process the payment in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to ask Stripe to charge a card as a "debit" or a "credit" card. There also isn't really a difference in charging either a debit/credit card when you create a Charge, Stripe just charges both cards the same way.

Comment: But what does it do when the card is both credit and debit, which is the case of my own card, it is both credit and debit, how does stripe decides which funding to use?

Comment: In those cases where the card supports both, it detects the card as "credit" but there isn't a technical difference AFAIK in how it would charge the card, regardless of it being detected as "debit" or "credit".